# how to escape a string correctly in a .bat file, so it can be output "as is" and not executed. Example, echo alfa < bravo

Tags: batch-file, escaping

How can I make a .bat file print this to the console window without executing anything, I get all sorts of errors. Expected output:

```
Syntax: cmd.cmd -p <path> -c <command>
commands: mv
path: ./dirname <- no trailing slash
```

So .bat file having this code is not working:

```
@echo off
rem This doesnt work, will give error
echo Syntax: cmd.cmd -p <path> -c <command>
echo commands: mv
echo ./dirname <- no trailing slash
 
rem This works, but leaves quotes around sentence
echo "Syntax: cmd.cmd -p <path> -c <command>"
echo "commands: mv"
echo "./dirname ^<- no trailing slash"
```

Question was how did I output to console without getting errors or quotes. Looking at response I have since understood it was not quite clear what I asked of so hopefully this is clearer now.

**UPDATED, THE SOLLUTION:**

For my .bat to work I need to prefix all < and > signs with a ^. Doing so treats the < > as a printable character removing any possible other meaning or function. So answering my question:

```
@echo off
rem Note all < and > are prefixed with a ^
echo Syntax: cmd.cmd -p ^<path^> -c ^<command^>
echo commands: mv
echo path: ./dirname ^<- no trailing slash
```

I'm guessing ^ is a windows equivilant of PHP's \ (backslash), so it boils down to a escape sequence.

Comment: put content inside quotes like: **echo "Syntax: cmd.cmd -p <path> -c <command>"**

Comment: If you're going down this route, I'd strongly suggest that you change your individual `.cmd` file names to ones which look similar to, _not replicate_, the names of actual commands. If you do not, you could well be heading for some problems moving forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to escape the < and > characters with a ^, so a correct .bat file would look like this:

```
@echo off
rem Note all < and > are prefixed with a ^
echo Syntax: cmd.cmd -p ^<path^> -c ^<command^>
echo commands: mv
echo path: ./dirname ^<- no trailing slash
```

Updated main question aswell so hopefully this question will never lead to any confusion for anyone.